# How to analyze unknown Common Lisp code with sbcl and slime

Tags: debugging, common-lisp, sbcl

**How to** analyze unknown common lisp source code, in order to understand it?

Given, I have Common Lisp source code of a function. That imaginary function operates on arbitrary and complex data. Now I'd like to analyze such a function.

So, I'm interestend in **working methods** to **analyze** some given common lisp **source code**. I.e. by stepping through source code, like it can be done with elisp source code in Emacs by using `edebug-defun`.
My tools are slime, sbcl and Emacs.

End of actual question, things below are written only to give a better overview, what this question is about.

---

*Notes about questions background:*

- I'm not interested in what the above given function does, since
- I already know basic common lisp like `if`, `dolist`, `defun` and basics. Also I also know how to query CLHS.
- I could probably go through code and data with pen and paper, but why? When I'm sitting in front of a computer.
- I already read [CL Cookbook - Debugging](https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/debugging.html) and [Malispers debugging tutorial](https://malisper.me/debugging-lisp-part-1-recompilation/)

---

Here is an *example* of such a function, the answer does **not** need to refer to this function:

```
(defun wins (grid color)
  (declare (optimize (speed 0)
                     (debug 3)))
  (dolist (phase *phase*)
    (dolist (start (car phase))
      (if (= (* 4 color)
             (reduce #'+ (cadr phase)
                     :key
                     (lambda (offset)
                       (aref grid (+ start offset)))))
        (return-from wins t)))))
```

Given above code, for me, it is a mystery when which parts of the arbitrary data is processed and how. It would probably be useful to see it in action.

With that special example, I tried to use `(step (wins ...))`, but this only stops at `(* 4 color)`, `(reduce ...` and `(* start offset)`, which is not enough (for me) to understand the function.

Also `(trace wins)` did not help much.

I took this function from an common lisp teaching book, which already explains it. So there is no need to explain this function.

Comment: mmh… your question is more suited for reddit's /r/common_lisp or another forum.

Comment: You could search for documentation of symbols and functions programmatically with `documentation`.

Comment: @Ehvince why should I search for documentation, when it does not exist, and I want to know how the function is processing given data?

Comment: `Foreign common lisp code` can also mean lisp code that deals with interfacing with other languages. https://www.common-lisp.net/project/cffi/ . I suggest using the phrase "Unknown Code" rather than foreign.